# How to efficiently split currency sign and number in one string without using a for loop or try statement

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I have a string like `'$200,000,000'` or `'Yan300,000,000'`

I want to split the currency and number, and output a tuple `('$', '200000000')`, without `','` in the number string.

Currently I'm using the following script, which is working:

```
def splitCurrency(cur_str):
    cuttingIdx = 0
    for char in cur_str:
        try:
            int(char)
            break
        except ValueError:
            cuttingIdx = cuttingIdx + 1
    return (cur_str[0:cuttingIdx].strip(),
            cur_str[cuttingIdx:len(cur_str)].replace(',',''))
```

I want to avoid using for-loop and try-except for performance and readability. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'YAN300,000,000'
>>> match = re.search(r'([\D]+)([\d,]+)', string)
>>> output = (match.group(1), match.group(2).replace(',',''))
>>> output
('YAN', '300000000')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> filter(str.isdigit, s)
'200000000'
>>> filter(lambda x: not x.isdigit() and x != ',', s)
'$'
>>> 
>>> (filter(lambda x: not x.isdigit() and x != ',' ,s), filter(str.isdigit, s))
('$', '200000000')
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import locale
import re
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

def split_currency(text):
    _, currency, num = re.split('^(\D+)', text, 1)
    num = locale.atoi(num)
    return currency, num
print(split_currency('$200,000,000'))
# ('$', 200000000)
print(split_currency('Yan300,000,000'))
# ('Yan', 300000000)
```

`split_currency` will raise a ValueError if `text` does not start with a currency symbol (or anything that is not a digit). You could use `try...except` to handle that case differently if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I want to avoid any try-except for performance, as I'm running this on large data.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> myStr = '$200,000,000'
>>> ''.join(itertools.dropwhile(lambda c: not c.isdigit(), myStr))
'200,000,000'
>>> myStr = 'Yan300,000,000'
>>> ''.join(itertools.dropwhile(lambda c: not c.isdigit(), myStr))
'300,000,000'
```

Similarly, you could use `itertools.takewhile` with the same `lambda` function to get the currency sign. However, this might be simpler:

```
idx = itertools.dropwhile(lambda c: not c.isdigit()).next()
sign, val = myStr[:idx], myStr[idx:]
```

Answer (score 0):

It wont be faster I bet ... but I think its more readable

```
>>> cur_string = "asd1,23456,123,1233"
>>> cur_sym = re.search(r"([^0-9, ]*)[0-9]","asd123").groups()[0]
>>> cur = re.sub("[^0-9]","",cur_string)
>>> print cur_sym,int(cur)
asd 1234561231233
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this.

```
p1 = re.compile("\d")  #match digits
p2 = re.compile("\D")  match non-digits


currency_symbol = p1.split(cur_str)[0]
value = int("".join([group for group in p2.split(cur_str)]))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if join is necessary for this task.